# How to call TranslateTo in ViewModel class?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I found this code on google, which shakes a "Entry" field. Issues is that this code is for the view and not viewmodel... Is it possiable to convert this code to call in viewmodel?

**UPDATE**: getting an error in view-behind: 'LoginPage' does not contain a definition for 'OnLoginFailed' and no accessible extension method 'OnLoginFailed' accepting a first argument of type 'LoginPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**view**

```
 <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse1" />
```

**view behind**

```
public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new LoginPage();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        viewModel.OnLoginFailed = ((obj) =>
        {
            uint timeout = 50;
            Ellipse1.TranslateTo(-15, 0, timeout);
            Ellipse1.TranslateTo(15, 0, timeout);
            Ellipse1.TranslateTo(-10, 0, timeout);
            Ellipse1.TranslateTo(10, 0, timeout);
            Ellipse1.TranslateTo(-5, 0, timeout);
            Ellipse1.TranslateTo(5, 0, timeout);
            Ellipse1.TranslationX = 0;
        });
        }
```

**viewmodel**

```
async void OnSubmitButtonClick()
{
    ...
    if(wrongPassword)
    {
        // i want to shake my Entry here. but viewmodel doesnt have access to "MyEntry" non "TranslateTo"
         OnLoginFailed?.Invoke(true);
    }
}

     public Action<bool> OnLoginFailed { get; set; }
```

Comment: if not possiable, than i will have to do all backend coding in view

Comment: TranslateTo is acting on a ui element so if you care about mvvm i would say it should be called in the code behind and not the vm.

Comment: animation is a UI concept and belongs in the View, not the VM.  Your VM can raise an event or use a bound property to trigger a view animation, or you could look at using an Effect or Behavior.

Comment: i see, makes sense. I can add TranslateTo code inside View. but is there way to call that method in VM? i am guessing not based on you guys said. but firgued i should just make sure

Comment: I will look into behavior. i am guess thats my best bet

Comment: Yes, I already pointed this out.  Your VM can raise an event that your View can subscribe to when it needs to trigger an animation.

Comment: great! this all was really helpful. i was able to raise an event in my VM to call view... but getting an error in my View

Answer (score 0):

there was a typo

change

```
 var viewModel = new LoginPage();
```

to

```
var viewModel = new LoginViewModel();
```